# Parse Cloud "beforeSave" not saving data

Tags: parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm using parse ***beforeSave*** method to save an order, here is the code:

```
    //Before save an order - if finish - set priority to 0
    Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserToOrders", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var preStatus = request.object.get("OrderStatus");
    if (preStatus == "Finish") {
        request.object.set("Priority",0);
        console.log("beforeSave(\"UserToOrders\")\t Order (" + request.object.id + ") Status is 'Finish' So Priority set to '0'");
    }
    else {
        console.log("beforeSave(\"UserToOrders\")\t Order (" + request.object.id + ") Status Changed to: " + preStatus);
        request.object.set("OrderStatus",preStatus);

    }
    response.success();
});
```

Here is the log:

```
I2016-03-09T20:56:05.779Z]v136 before_save triggered for UserToOrders for user pSi0iCGJJe:
  Input: {"original":{"ACL":{"*":{"read":true},"vxgEWFQ7eu":{"read":true,"write":true}},"OrderStatus":"Ready","OrderStatusActivity":"Active","ResturantID":"g1bzMQEXoj","TimeToBeReady":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2016-03-08T23:35:23.916Z"},"UserETA":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2016-03-08T23:35:23.916Z"},"UserID":"vxgEWFQ7eu","createdAt":"2016-03-08T21:06:06.605Z","objectId":"t3NoxcSp5z","updatedAt":"2016-03-08T21:40:59.538Z"},"update":{"OrderStatus":"Finish","objectId":"t3NoxcSp5z"}}
  Result: Update changed to {"OrderStatus":"Finish","Priority":0}

I2016-03-09T20:56:05.975Z]beforeSave("UserToOrders")     Order (t3NoxcSp5z) Status is 'Finish' So Priority set to '0'
```

but nothing is being changed in the DB.

What do i miss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in var preStatus is the same value as you wanted to save...

```
var preStatus = request.object.get("OrderStatus");
```

and you are "saving" the same value, you can just delete this line

```
request.object.set("OrderStatus",preStatus);
```

if it is not what you want, provide the log from "OrderStatus" = Finish

Comment: your code looks like it should work, I would try putting the else statement on the same line as the curly bracket or try to put some string in response.success("It worked...");

Comment: Thanks. Finally I've figured it out, it was an ACL permissions issue.

Comment: I have 2 android projects apps using the same parse app, one is the client side and the other one is the store and they both need to update the same rows in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It was an ACL permissions issue. 
The Order created by one client, while the chance made by another one.